# Order items by custom order

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a list which I inserted on a database:

```
List<House> houses = new List<House> {
  new House { Id = 1, Type = "A" },
  new House { Id = 2, Type = "B" },
  new House { Id = 3, Type = "C" }
  new House { Id = 4, Type = "B" }
}
```

Using Linq to Entities I need to get Houses ordered by Type but it should be:

```
 Houses of Type C
 Houses of Type A
 Houses of Type B
```

How to do this?

Comment: Can you do something like this? houses.OrderBy(h => h.Type = "C").ThenBy(h => h.Type="A") etc. I can't remember off the top of my head sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can add some OrderNumber field to the database and then order by that field instead of some custom order sort. Or if you provid another table where sort order would be provided (meaning records in the table are "C", "A", "B" in that order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can chain the `? :` opeartor to create a custom sort like this:

```
var query = from h in context.Houses
            orderby h.Type == "C" ? 0 : (h.Type == "A" ? 1 : 2)
            select h;
```

Or method syntax

```
var query = context.Houses.OrderBy(h => h.Type == "C" ? 0 : (h.Type == "A" ? 1 : 2))
```

Comment: It wont be readable after few elements in your list ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late answer, but I would write an extension similar to this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.AsQueryable();

        //for example, revert entire list
        var newOrder = new Dictionary<int, int>() { { 1, 5 }, { 2, 4 }, { 3, 3 }, { 4, 2 }, { 5, 1 } };
        var sorted = items.OrderBy(newOrder.ToSwithExpression())).ToList();

        foreach(var i in sorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static Expression<Func<T, K>> ToSwithExpression<T, K>(this Dictionary<T, K> dict, K defaultValue = default(K))
    {
        var paramm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        //If nothing maps - use default value.
        Expression iter = Expression.Constant(defaultValue);
        foreach (var kv in dict)
        {
            iter = Expression.Condition(Expression.Equal(paramm, Expression.Constant(kv.Key)), Expression.Constant(kv.Value, typeof(K)), iter);
        }

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, K>>(Expression.Convert(iter, typeof(K)), paramm);
    }
```

As you see you can specify mapping switch instead of Dictionary. I used dictionary just because it is easier. EF will have no problem in chewing this one and transforming it into similar to other answers expression.